# firebase pub/sub function setting the delivery type to "PUSH" by default I want it to be type "PULL"

Tags: asynchronous, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, pull

I'm trying to create a function which triggers through pub/sub topic and it creates a subscription by default in the console.
All I want is the subscription delivery type to be "PULL" by default on creation instead of the "PUSH".
Appreciate the Help!

Comment: There is only one type of pubsub trigger, and it will be invoked at least once for each message published on the specified topic.  Are you looking for some other type of behavior? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

Comment: @DougStevenson I want the subscription to be of type pull (by default) when I deploy a firebase function see here like this: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull
I'm not sure if it can be done or other way I need to pull the message data Asynchronously in the function body guide me about this.

Comment: What is the change in behavior that you're looking for?

Comment: let me make it simple I want something like this:
pubsub.topic(topicName).subscription(subscriptionName).modifyPushConfig('pushEndpoint: `https://${pubsub.projectId}.appspot.com/pull`');
console.log(`Modified push config for subscription ${subscriptionName}.`);

For this function:
exports.helloFunction = functions.pubsub.topic('topicName').onPublish((message, context) => {
    // some stuff here
});

So when the function deploys it creates a subscription with PULL type by default.

Comment: How would you expect that to change the behavior of the function?

Comment: I read those instruction here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#pubsub-create-subscription-nodejs

Comment: @Rehan This reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And in this case, it seems like the thing you're trying to do is not possible. But there may be another way to accomplish your use-case. So what are you trying to accomplish by changing the pubsub delivery type?

Comment: So when the function deployed the subscription associated to it created must be of type PULL by default but its currently PUSH type and I have to manually change from the console.

Comment: You still haven't really said why you need to change the subscription type.  It's almost certainly not possible to do so, but I'd like to understand why you feel the need to change it.  Do you need the function to behave differently than it does now?  If not, then just accept its behavior and don't worry about it.

Comment: I'm trying to do because using asynchronous pulling provides higher throughput in the application, by not requiring the application to block for new messages.
and I'm really not sure if this can be achieved like this or some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment of creation you can decide which is the type of the subscription.

I will share an example of creation of pull subscriptions in Java, but in [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#pubsub-create-subscription-java) you can choose any language you prefer.

```
  /** Example of creating a pull subscription for a topic. */
  public Subscription createSubscription(String topicId, String subscriptionId) throws Exception {
    // [START pubsub_create_pull_subscription]
    try (SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient.create()) {
      // eg. projectId = "my-test-project", topicId = "my-test-topic"
      ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
      // eg. subscriptionId = "my-test-subscription"
      ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName =
          ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
      // create a pull subscription with default acknowledgement deadline
      Subscription subscription =
          subscriptionAdminClient.createSubscription(
              subscriptionName, topicName, PushConfig.getDefaultInstance(), 0);
      return subscription;
    }
    // [END pubsub_create_pull_subscription]
  }
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm still confused how to properly pull data asynchronously using an auto created subscription through pub/sub onPublish event.

Comment: there are ways to do it both ways synchronous and asynchronous. [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull) are some examples of how to pull the data

Comment: Is there a way I can auto detect the subscription created by pubsub function and not have to do this: const subscription = pubsub.subscription(subscriptionName);